# php Obtaining Value from JSON Array

Tags: php, json

I am having problem trying to access the value "total" inside this decoded json array. Any advise is appreciated.

**PHP Code**

```
$json = json_decode($response, true); //$response coming from curl
```

**JSON Output**

```
array(2) {
  ["links"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["rel"]=>
      string(4) "self"
      ["href"]=>
      string(11) "https://api"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["rel"]=>
      string(8) "metadata"
      ["href"]=>
      string(11) "https://api"
    }
  }
  ["items"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["total"]=>
      float(18.36)  //Need to retrieve this value
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from the looks of it, items is an array, so unless you know something about the data, you cant be sure there are not more than one total.

The direct answer specifically would be

```
$json['items'][0]['total'];
```

But if you expect there could be more than one entry in items, that would only give you the first result, so in that case you may use a foreach to loop over items to extract information, or perhaps make a sum using the column.

Comment: I just realized that I have used double quotes instead of single quote. Thank you,

Comment: Double or single makes no difference. PHP gives the option of using variables inside double quotes so there is some extra functionality to double quotes. This, however, makes no difference in this situation :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple if i am not misreading your array:

```
<?php
$total = $json['items'][0]['total'];
```

Comment: I just realized that I have used double quotes instead of single quote. Thank you,

Comment: He David. This will make no difference in the result. mortendhansen explains.